# What is the reason of having a "Dispatch" function on an Event?

Tags: c++, events, design-patterns, architecture, event-handling

I have been reading about event managers and I understand the basic mechanics, or so I thought. I have been seeing situations where something such as

```
IEvent* pEvent = m_events;

while(pEvent)   {
    removeEvent(pEvent);
    pEvent->Dispatch(); // What is this?
    pEvent = pEvent->Next;
}
```

However, what is the point of doing "pEvent->Dispatch"? I thought it would have something to do with the event listening, but I am not exactly sure to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "listening" for events has already completed by the time the code fragment you presented is being called. After "listening", all the events have been collected in some container, and each event needs to be processed. The `Dispatch` is likely a virtual method on the `IEvent` class, so that each derived event can be handled by a routine specific to that kind of event.

```
class IEvent {
protected:
    virtual ~IEvent () {}
    virtual void Dispatch () = 0;
    //...
};
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want the `Dispatch` method to be `protected`?

Comment: @maba: I was thinking the dispatch loop would be a static function in `IEvent` itself. I could have made it private, but protected is just my habitual default for interface classes.

Comment: OK, I prefer to make them public so they correspond to an interface in Java for example. And then they can be called from an EventManager or similar.

Comment: I just want to make sure, so if the event was something like CREATE_OBJECT, in the Dispatch, that is where the Dispatch is suppose to create the object?

Comment: @mmurphy: The dispatch may defer processing of an event for its own reasons, but yes, generally speaking the dispatch routine for the event runs the code the handle the event.